# GenericDAO - Está correto?

Tags: java, interface

Estou implementando um simples `GenericDAO` conforme abaixo, mas sinto que estou fazendo coisa errada, ele funciona mas sinto que tem coisa errada mesmo assim, poderiam me ajudar?

Criei uma interface assim:

```
public interface GenericDAO<T, ID> {
    public List<T> listaTodos(Class<T> clazz);
    public List<T> listaComLimite(Class<T> clazz, Integer limite);
    public T porId(Class<T> clazz, ID id);
    public void adiciona(T t);
    public T grava(T t);
    public void remove(Class<T> clazz, ID id);
}
```

Depois criei uma outra interface (mais específica), ou seja com aquilo que não é genérico, porém como podemos ver essa `extends` do `GenericDAO` anterior:

```
public interface TestDAO extends GenericDAO<Test, Long> {
    public Test buscaPorNome(String nome);
}
```

Abaixo estou testando como ficaria o uso:

```
public void getTest(){
    Test teste = testDAO.porId(Test.class, id);
}
```

Parece besteira, mas quando eu estendi o `GenericDAO` eu já passei a classe alvo:

```
extends GenericDAO<Test, Long>
```

A pergunta é, porque quando vou usar preciso passar novamente, assim?

```
Test teste = testDAO.porId(Test.class, id);
```

Não parece errado isso?

Answer (score 7):

Não há nada de errado com seu código. Muitos *frameworks* utilizam essa abordagem com parâmetros do tipo `Class<T>` para contornar as limitações da implementação de genéricos do Java (em suma o problema é que `<T>` é "apagado" em tempo de execução).

Dito isso, há um *workaround* conhecido para esse tipo de situação. Caso suas classes estendam uma classe de base genérica você pode extrair esse tipo genérico da superclasse através de reflexão.

Por exemplo, se você tem um classe `GenericDaoImpl<T>` e uma subclasse específica `SpecificDaoImpl extends GenericDaoImpl<Specific>`):

```
private final Class<T> minhaClasse; 

public GenericDaoImpl() {
    minhaClasse = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass())
            .getActualTypeArguments()[0];

}
```

A vantagem aqui é que você não precisa passar o tipo de classe nunca.

Alternativamente, para não ter que lidar com reflexão, você também pode utilizar o construtor da classe genérica para receber o tipo (e especificar o tipo como argumento no construtor da classe específica uma única vez):

```
private final Class<T> minhaClasse;

public GenericDaoImpl(Class<T> minhaClasse) {
    this.minhaClasse = minhaClasse;
}

// E na classe específica
public SpecificDaoImpl() {
    super(TipoDaMinhaClasseEspecífica);
}
```

Não sei te dizer qual implementação seria "mais correta". Vale a pena utilizar o que for mais prático no seu caso.

---

**Fonte:** [*SOen - Get generic type of class at runtime*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3403909/664577).

Comment: Fuçando os comentários no SOen encontrei a biblioteca [TypeTools](https://github.com/jhalterman/typetools) capaz de resolver os tipos "crús".

Comment: Olá Anthony,

Sua resposta foi perfeita, fiz o teste pelo construtor e realmente ficou menos repetitivo o trabalho.

Muito obrigado!!!

Espero um dia ficar bom no JAVA e OO para poder ajudar tb...

Abs. Marcelo

Comment: Olá Marcelo. Fico feliz em ter ajudado.Tenho certeza que você ainda irá contribuir para a comunidade. Se a resposta resolveu o seu problema não se esqueça de aceitá-la.